# Bash script - trying to get path of script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I need to get the path of script.

I can do this manually with `pwd` but after searching online and I found this script:

```
DIR=$( cd $(dirname $0) ; pwd)
```

I don't know what it means. Can someone please explain?

edit:this script is different from that script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It identifies the directory that contains the script (which might be different than the current working directory).

You'd commonly use a pattern like this if you needed to refer to files in the same directory:

```
# contents of myscript.sh
DIR=$( cd $(dirname $0) ; pwd)
cat $DIR/some-file-next-to-my-script.txt
```

Then from *anywhere* on the file system:

```
/path/to/myscript.sh
```

would actually print the contents of `some-file-next-to-my-script.txt`. If you stuck to `pwd` alone, you'd be looking for that file in your current working directory, which may or may not be the behavior you want.

Breaking down the command:

```
$( cd $(dirname $0); pwd)
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

That identifies the directory containing `$0`. If you invoked the script as `/path/to/myscript.txt`, then `dirname $0` evaluates to `/path/to`. If you invoked it as `./myscript.txt`, then `dirname $0` simply evaluates to `.`.

```
$( cd $(dirname $0); pwd)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
```

Change to the directory as before, but critically, in a *subshell* so that *your* working directory isn't modified.

Then the final `pwd` simply prints out that current working directory, which will *always* be expanded to the full path. That value is then stored in the `DIR` variable in your example.

Comment: what is the use use of $0 after dirname

Comment: $0 is the name of the script. In this example, it would be `/path/to/myscript.sh` (if that's how you called it). Or if you did `cd /path/to` and called it as `./myscript.sh`, then `$0` would be `./myscript,sh`. Because `$0` changes its value depending on how exactly the script is called, people do exactly the trick you asked about to try to find where the script is being run from.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so does this tell me where my script file is located in './myscript.sh'

Comment: Added a bit more to the explanation to make it clearer what is going on.

Comment: I think this answer is perfect Thank you

Comment: @dtanabe :Wouldn't be DIR=$(dirname $(realpath $0)) or DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0)) a more natural (easier to understand) way?

Comment: There are many variations on this technique, but the question was specifically about the meaning of the specific line he saw in a shell script and what its purpose was.

Answer (score 1):

`DIR=$( cd $(dirname $0) ; pwd )`

suppose your script is `/home/lanzhiwang/work/py_web/multimediaapi_lab/pukep.py`

$0 is pukep.py

$(dirname $0) is /home/lanzhiwang/work/py_web/multimediaapi_lab/

cd /home/lanzhiwang/work/py_web/multimediaapi_lab/

pwd

DIR = /home/lanzhiwang/work/py_web/multimediaapi_lab/

Comment: $0 is pukep.py can you please elaborate this point?